What is the actual nuance of あてられた here in this sentence?

また、どこからか熱が沸き上がる。時たま吹くビル風にも関わらず、自分の目許はあてられたように熱っぽくなっていく

I understand what the sentence means overall, but I'm stumbled on the actual meaning of "あてられた" here. The more direct meaning would be "as if hit"? but I don't think it's quite correct. Is there a specific meaning related to heat for あてられる? The character is just being emotional/embarrassed for context.

あてる has a sense "expose to (elements)". In this line, あてられる has an idiomatic meaning "influenced by bad atmosphere, environment". Of course "atmosphere" and "environment" are modern interpretation instead of "bad air" or "spell" or "aura", which are probably closer to the original intent.
In your example, "by what" part is not explicitly indicated, but from the context, it obviously means 熱にあてられる, where you can picture a symptom like dizziness, hot flash, or hyperthermia, as a figure of speech.
